# php curl - parse return var from url

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get the `code` variable from Instagrams api using cURL.
The `url` is `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code`
Which produces a return-url `https://www.myredirecturi.com?code=MY-CODE` when entering the `url` in my browser.
I would like to capture `MY-CODE` using `cURL`.
This is what I have but it echo's out nothing.

```
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

`CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` and `CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL` both returns the same `$url` that I input from line 1.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_exec($ch);
$last_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
echo $last_url;
curl_close($ch);
```

Even if I parse it out from header using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);`, `Location` has the same `$url`

This works `header("Location: " . $url);`,  but I would like to use cURL

Answer (score 0):

If the response is a redirect then you should check the location header in order to get the url:

`var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL));`

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php for more information.